# EF Code First composite key mapping

Tags: entity-framework-4, mapping, fluent

I'm using the CTP 5 of EF 4 and Code first.
I don't get a many-many relation working with a composite key on one side.

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()                 
           .HasMany(i => i.Categories)  
           .WithMany(o => o.Items)  
           .Map(
           mc =>
           {                  
               mc.ToTable("ItemCategories");  
               mc.MapLeftKey(i => i.Id, "ItemId");  
               mc.MapRightKey(o => o.TemplateID, "TemplateId");  
               mc.MapRightKey(o => o.ItemId, "ItemId");                  
           }
           );
```

So instead of having a simple key for Categories in my matching table, I've got a composite one. And one part of the composite key is also the key for the Item type,
which seems to be the problem here.

I get the error:  "Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'ItemId' was already defined."

How can I configure EF to use a composite key in this case?

Comment: Please show your object model. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you cannot have 2 columns with the same name within one table. This will work:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasMany(i => i.Categories)
            .WithMany(c => c.Items)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.MapRightKey(i => i.Id, "ItemId");
                m.MapLeftKey(c => c.ItemId, "ItemId2");
                m.MapLeftKey(c => c.TemplateId, "TemplateId");
            });
```

Comment: I see, but the MapLeftKey is a composite key(ItemId+TemplateId), so the ItemId is really the same than on the right hand side.

Comment: That doesn't matter because Code First does not know about that and will create a join table containing *all* the key columns from both tables.

Comment: I don't have a ItemId2 column in that table. I get an {"Invalid column name 'ItemId2'."} All I want is to reuse that same column for a composite key relation on the category table. Is that possible?

Comment: Please show your complete object model as well as your join table schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Category
{            
    [Key]        
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public string TemplateId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{       
    public string Id { get; set; }       
    public string Name { get; set; }      

    public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping table ItemCategories is not a POCO, but used for mapping those 2 as
shown.
It has SQL columns
Id (own primary key)
ItemId (FK to Item table and Category table)
TemplateId (FK to Category table)

and another ID column which maps to a different table.

In my opinion the only difference here to "normal" many-many scenario is the composite key 
in the ItemCategories table, which builds the relation to the Category table.